Applying auto _only_ to the created proof goals in tactic mode
I want to apply auto to all the proof goals the previous apply created, but not the other ones. I only know how to do it by putting everything in a subgoal. Is there a nicer way?
lemma bar:
  assumes p: "⋀a b. length a = b ⟹ (a ! 0) > b ⟹ P a"
      and q: "⋀x. x = ([2] @ [3]) ⟹ Q x"
    shows "x = ([2] @ [3]) ⟹ y = [5,6] ⟹ P y ∧ Q x"
  apply (rule conjI)
  subgoal
    apply (rule p)
     apply auto
    done
  apply (erule q)
  done

If I don't it breaks:
lemma bar:
  assumes p: "⋀a b. length a = b ⟹ (a ! 0) > b ⟹ P a"
      and q: "⋀x. x = ([2] @ [3]) ⟹ Q x"
    shows "x = ([2] @ [3]) ⟹ y = [5,6] ⟹ P y ∧ Q x"
  apply (rule conjI)
   apply (rule p)
    apply auto
(* ⟦x = [2, 3]; y = [5, 6]⟧ ⟹ Q [2, 3] *)
  apply (erule q) ― ‹Doesn't work because auto stuffed up the proof goal›
  done

Neither ; or , do what I want. ; leaves a trivial proof goal and , messes up the other goals:
lemma bar':
  assumes p: "⋀ra rb. length ra = rb ⟹ (ra ! 0) > rb ⟹ P ra"
      and q: "⋀x. x = ([2] @ [3]) ⟹ Q x"
    shows "x = ([2] @ [3]) ⟹ y = [5,6] ⟹ P y ∧ Q x"
  apply (rule conjI)
   apply (rule p; auto)
(* 
 1. ⟦x = [2, 3]; y = [5, 6]⟧ ⟹ Suc (Suc 0) < 5
 2. ⟦x = [2] @ [3]; y = [5, 6]⟧ ⟹ Q x
*)
  apply simp ― ‹Why is this needed?›
  apply (erule q)
  done

lemma bar'':
  assumes p: "⋀ra rb. length ra = rb ⟹ (ra ! 0) > rb ⟹ P ra"
      and q: "⋀x. x = ([2] @ [3]) ⟹ Q x"
    shows "x = ([2] @ [3]) ⟹ y = [5,6] ⟹ P y ∧ Q x"
  apply (rule conjI)
   apply (rule p, auto)
(* ⟦x = [2, 3]; y = [5, 6]⟧ ⟹ Q [2, 3] *)
  apply (erule q) ― ‹Doesn't work because auto stuffed up the proof goal›
  done


The ; combinator chains two proof methods together in such a way that the second one is only applied to subgoals created by the first one. Apparently it also works for "unusual" methods like auto and simp_all that normally act on all subgoals:
consts P :: "bool"
consts Q :: "bool"

lemma A [intro]: P
  and B: "Q ⟹ P"
  and C [intro]: Q
  sorry

lemma "P ∧ P"
  apply (rule conjI)
   apply (rule B; auto)
  apply (rule A)
  done

As you can see, the second subgoal P is still around after the second apply, even though auto can see it. If you just do apply (rule B) apply auto or apply (rule B, auto) it will be gone, too.
Another useful thing you might be interested in: You can restrict auto to only act on the first n subgoals by writing apply auto[n], or on the first subgoal by writing apply auto[].
